# Show deleted emails in Office 2013 conversation view

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, user-interface

[Another](https://superuser.com/questions/896464/only-show-unread-senders-in-outlook-2013-conversation-view) major efficiency-reducing problem with Office 2013 is that they have filtered out items from the Deleted Items folder from conversation view, even if you select the "Show Message from Other Folders" options.  I like to delete messages quickly, but sometimes when a new one pops up, it's useful to be able to quickly browse back through the prior emails.  Worked great in 2010.  In 2013, I have to select Deleted Items and search for the thread.

Any way to get items from the Deleted Items folder in the expanded conversation view?

Thanks.

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually there, but not intuitive.  Go to the Search Toolbar (by clicking on search box), then Search Tools ? Search Options.  Finally, click on "include messages from the Deleted items folder".  Now, when you have conversation turned on, you'll see emails from all your folders, including Deleted.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently my account wasn't set up to notify me on replies, so I only just now saw this! I wish I could have "search" ignore deleted items but expanded conversations show them, but that would be too much to ask for!